# Why would IE9 launch when IE11 is installed?

Tags: internet-explorer

We have recently deployed IE11 to all our desktops, in order to support a new application (which has already gone live). We have already (manually) checked every workstation prior to go-live, and visually confirmed that they all had IE 11 installed.

Over the past few days, some users are reporting that they have IE9 installed. We have gone back and checked these, and launching IE does indeed seem to be IE9. However, in Windows Features, it's showing IE11 (and as enabled).

How is this possible and what can we do to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my junior helpdesk techs figured it out - the computers with this issue occurring were missing SP1.